# Connection Jenkins slave to master aborted : Ping response time is too long or timed out

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, slave

I am trying to establish a connection between Jenkins master (Linux Debian) and a slave (Windows 7). However, the connection is rapidly aborted with the following message:
*Ping response time is too long or timed out.*

I can't find a solution to this problem. Could someone help me?

Comment: Please at first specify, what is the slave launch method do you use?

Comment: It's launched via JNLP (Java Network Launching Protocol)

Comment: Not enough info to guess. Please describe your actions step by step on which host what you do exactly, do you use browser or cmd "java -jar slave jar", have you tried to ping the hosts from each other, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you confirmed you actually have connectivity between the master and the node (ping, traceroute, ssh) ?

JNLP (as noted in your comment) uses a random port >  50000 for the back comms. You may want to verify that too.

You might change the following to fixed port:
Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Configure Global Security
Agents TCP port for inbound agents: [o] Random

See my clarification response on [JNLP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980939/598141) or alternatively, [via DCOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268806/598141). Also review [Troubleshooting WMI Windows Agents](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc) (or start there).

Not sure, but you may want to try adjust one of the following [System Properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties):

**hudson.ProxyConfiguration.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS** [ 20000 ]
Connection timeout applied to connections e.g. to the update site.
**hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingIntervalSeconds** [ 300 ]
Frequency of pings between the master and slaves, in seconds

**hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingTimeoutSeconds** [ 240 ]
Timeout for each ping between the master and slaves, in seconds

**org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD.idle-timeout** [ undefined ]
Allows to configure the SSHD client idle timeout (value in milliseconds). Default value is 10min (600000ms).

Ps: did not notice this was an old Q. Advice still applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security, and under Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy, enable “connect” in the “slave” section, for user “Anonymous”. This would leave you open to attack where someone emulates a slave (but in my case, on a private work network - that's not an issue.)