# Jenkins agent often disconnects from master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

In my company currently, we use Jenkins 2.204.2 version. And we have a lot of agents. One of the agents which runs as a service in a Windows machine often disconnects. As a workaround solution we restart service and it connects again but this solution is really annoying. The output log when the agent is disconnected is like below

```
Connection was broken: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:209)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:784)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:172)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:314)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1450)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1403)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.closeChannel(SlaveComputer.java:843)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.access$100(SlaveComputer.java:108)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$2.run(SlaveComputer.java:734)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


I'm looking for a permanent solution but I'm having trouble investigating the problem. Actually I don't know where I am supposed to look (don't know should I check jenkins logs or java version or something else). Could you please help me about this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you in advance.
```

The outputs of **java -version** command, on controller which is CentOS 7 as following

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

on agent running on Windows Server 2019

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I faced a similar issue in the past, and problem was linked to a regular reboot/patching corporate policy. Can you also print the output of what happens on the windows jenkins agent when this disconnection occurs ? Are those windows agents regularely rebooted / patched ? Check the uptime on windows agent machine after such disconnect.

Comment: Also has similar issues as @MorganGeek as WIN systems were patched. Switched to launch via [DCOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268806/598141) w/o issues (after security setting).

Comment: @MorganGeek There is no regular reboot, this happens when server is online. In windows event logs there is an event that says "SIGINT to 9548 failed - Killing as fallback"

Comment: @IanW I tried to switch to launch via DCOM but I ended up with [the error](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc#remote-agent---windows-returned-error-code-0x8001ffff), I did the same thing as in your link described, also tried the solution in the github link they both didn't work..